# How to use UICollectionViewFlowLayout.prepare() with Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm attempting to make a UICollectionViewFlowLayout that arranges items like a UITableView and includes supplementary view headers. The items use auto layout. Apple's documentation is unclear about working with auto layout items. It seems like prepare() expects you to know the size of each item, but I don't see how you would figure that out?

Comment: You can call the [Delegate functions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout) in the prepare, probably you get the Auto Layout sizes there?